# Iterate over a MultiSet

Tags: haskell

This question relates to Data.MultiSet type, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html
I would like to iterate over a given MultiSet to create a new MultiSet. For every element in the MultiSet, there will either be created one element in the new multiset or two new elements in the new MultiSet.
I thougth this could be done using tail recursion, however I dont think it is possible to do with a MultiSet.

```hs
tailRecursion :: (Multiset String) -> (MultiSet String)
tailRecursion (x:xs) = do 
  -- if check x then (add one element tailRecursion xs) else (add two elements to the MultiSet tailRecursion xs)
```

I was thinking of doing this using map, however it is not possible (as I understood) to map a Multiset of size n to a Multiset of size, x>n.

How could this be implemented with Data.MultiSet?

Comment: Is that https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html you're talking about? Please always make stuff like that clear in the question. Also, it's unclear what the question is even asking.

Comment: yes I am talking about this, Data.MultiSet

Comment: `:` is a data constructor for `[a]`, not an all-purpose syntax for retrieving the next item of an iterable value.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to lists, multisets provide a [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html#v:concatMap) function.

```
concatMap :: Ord b => (a -> [b]) -> MultiSet a -> MultiSet b
```

`concatMap` is your general-purpose "do something to each element of the data structure, and that something might produce zero or more results" operation.

```
concatMap (\x -> if check x then [oneElement] else [firstElement, secondElement]) myMultiSet
```

Note that `concatMap` *would* just be the monadic bind operator `>>=` (and, indeed, it *is* exactly that on lists), but `MultiSet` can't be a monad since it only functions correctly if the underlying type is `Ord`